# Can I merge two Non-sequential partitions without losing data?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, merge

Is it possible to merge two Non-sequential partitions without losing data (running windows) ?

what i want is similar to move empty space from partition to another.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.

But what you can do is open **Disk Management** and mount an NTFS partition in another NTFS partition as a sub folder.

For example, you could mount the former `D:` partition as `C:\Data` and for programs (including Windows Explorer) it looks as if it would be a regular folder.